# Google Drive PC application files sync changes their links

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive PC application to sync some csv files that will be later downloaded by an android application using drive REST API by their links.

The problem is that any update to the files and resync changes their links. Anyway to make the Google Drive PC application update the files without changing links like uploading a new version?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To update files in Drive without changing the link**, you can try to follow this steps that can found [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/update-files-in-google-drive/28928/).

1. Go to your Google Drive and select any file that you would like to update. This is applicable for files that are not in that native Google Docs format like PDF, images, text files or even videos.
2. Right-click the file, choose Manage Versions from the menu and then click the Upload new version button to upload the updated file to your Google Drive.
3. That’s it. The file name and the file’s URL won’t change and thus all the old shared links will now automatically point to the new version of your file.

**For creating download links for files in Google Drive**, you can check this [page](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/).